# Regex to parse delimited string with key/value pairs (python)

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have data in text format, where key/value pairs are separated by semi-colon, may be followed by whitespace, maybe not, e.g., ";" or ";  ", or even " ; ". There will always be a semi-colon between pairs, and the string is terminated with a semi-colon.

Keys and values are separated by whitespace.

This string is flat. There's never anything nested. Strings are always quoted and numerical values are never quoted. I can count on this being consistent in the input. So for example,

```
'cheese "stilton";pigeons 17; color "blue"; why "because I said so";'
```

Ultimately this winds up as

```
{'cheese': "stilton", 'pigeons': 17, 'color': "blue"; 'why': "because I said so"}
```

Different strings may include different key/value pairs, and I can't know in advance which keys will be present. So this is equally valid input string:

```
mass 6.02 ; mammal "gerbil";telephone "+1 903 555-1212"; size "A1";
```

I'm thinking that a regex to split the string into a list would be a good start, then just iterate through the list by twos to build the dictionary. Something like

```
x = PATTERN.split(s)
d = {}
for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    d[x[i]] = d[x[i+1]]
```

Which requires a list like ['cheese', 'stilton', 'pigeons', 17, 'color', 'blue', 'why', 'because I said so']. But I can't figure out a regex to get in this form. Closest I have is

```
([^;[\s]*]+)
```

Which returns

```
['', 'cheese', ' ', '"stilton"', ';', 'pigeons', ' ', '17', '; ', 'color', ' ', '"blue"', '; ', 'why', ' ', '"because', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'said', ' ', 'so"', ';']
```

Of course, it's easy enough to iterate by threes and pick the key/value pairs and ignore the captured delimiters, but I'm wondering if there's a different regex that would not capture the delimiters. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to use `findall()` instead of `split()` here. This will let you use a capture group to pull out just the part you want. Then you can split the groups, cleanup, etc:

```
import re
s = 'cheese "stilton";pigeons 17; color "blue"; why "because I said so";'
pairs = re.findall(r'(\S+?) (.+?);', s)

d = {}
for k, v in pairs:
    if  v.isdigit():
        v = int(v)
    else:
        v = v.strip('"')
    d[k] = v
print(d)
```

**result**

```
{'cheese': 'stilton',
 'pigeons': 17,
 'color': 'blue',
 'why': 'because I said so'}
```

This, of course, assumes you aren't using `;` anywhere in the data.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
r'(\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|[^\s;]+)'
```

to match and extract your data with `re.findall`, and post-process Group 2 values to remove one trailing and one leading `"` chars if the first alternative matched, and then create a dictionary entry.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ghsiH0/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (key): one or more word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `("[^"]*"|[^\s;]+)` - Group 2: `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"` or 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `;`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/efzmYT):

```
import re
rx = r'(\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|[^\s;]+)'
s = 'cheese "stilton";pigeons 17; color "blue"; why "because I said so";'
result = {}
for key,val in re.findall(rx, s):
    if val.startswith('"') and val.endswith('"'):
        val = val[1:-1]
    result[key]=val

print(result)
```